# did i use lgbm correctly for categorical features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

Suppose my data has only 1 column of categorical feature (already converted it to astype(int)),

```
x_to_use = x_to_use.astype(int)
```

I am using this in a sklearn Pipeline:

```
                                LGBMRegressor(**{
                                            "n_estimators":100,
                                    "categorical_feature":(0,),
                                            "max_depth":1,
                                        }
```

I got this warning.

```
c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py:842: UserWarning: categorical_feature keyword has been found in `params` an
Please use categorical_feature argument of the Dataset constructor to pass this parameter.
```

I want everything to be in standard sklearn machine learning pipeline format, so my input is always np.array. Is my pipeline construction correct or is                                  "categorical_feature":(0,), simply ignored and that column is not treated as categorical.

**Edit:**

OK... I constructed a simple test, "categorical_feature" is actually used correctly.

Comment: ok... i constructed a simple test, it can indeed treat "categorical_feature" correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

-categorical_feature (list of strings or int, or 'auto', optional (default='auto'))

Have you tried passing a list like this?

```
LGBMRegressor(**{"n_estimators":100,
                 "categorical_feature":[0],
                 "max_depth":1}
```